# Set class using data source from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to build a list of data source received from JavaScript in `vue.js`

```
<div class="{{item.clockIn}}"></div>
```

Where this `{{item.clockIn}}` return two type of value that is `true` and `false`.

```
.true {
content: 'IN';
color: blue;
}
.true {
content: 'OUT';
color: red;
}
```

But it's not working as i thought. Anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Are you having problem in getting the data for the item.clockIn itself or are you having problem displaying the content and color from the css file

Comment: Hi! I hope it helps you. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html and binding should be in this format `:class={active}`

Comment: Henry Ly, problem to set class by using the item.clockIn.
{{Item.clocking}} is working to display as value. just not work to use as class value.

Comment: SJSJSJSJ i've read this before. but i have problem where this <div> is in ant-design list. so it will uses the same class for every line of the list. so some of the list will get true value and some will get false value. i didn't know how to apply that vbind:class in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you seem to have a typo in your class definition. The second `.true` class should be `.false`. Then you can use something like this:

```
<div :class="item.clockIn ? 'true' : 'false'"></div>
```

This makes the `class` property reactive and getting the value related to the `item.clockIn` directly.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:-

```
<div v-bind:class="{ 'true': true, 'false': false }"></div>
```

Code:-

```
data: {
  true: true,
  false: false
}
```

CSS:-

```
.true {
  content: 'IN';
  color: blue;
}

.false {
  content: 'OUT';
  color: red;
}
```

output:-
If the condition is true

```
<div class="true"></div>
```

If the condition is false

```
<div class="false"></div>
```

[class-and-style](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)